# Add Object To Other Object Scripts that require an Object

Tags: unity-game-engine

Ok , I have problem with adding object let's first see what is this about.
I Have Map when i click at map i create Sphere on map.
then i serialized the point, msg and name .....

```
void Start () {


    Ser = new Serial();
    Ser.read();


    for (int i =0 ; i < Ser.list.Count; i++)
    {


        Data d = new Data();
        d = Ser.list[i];
        GameObject a = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        a.name = d.Id;
        a.transform.position = new Vector3(d.x,d.y,0);
        a.transform.localScale  =new Vector3(0.5f , 0.5f , 0.5f);



        Follow putTarget = new Follow();
        Data Pos_In_File  = new Data();
        Pos_In_File = Ser.list[i];

        GUIText GText = new GUIText();
        Vector3 SP = new Vector3();
        GameObject TextObj = new GameObject("GUIText" + Convert.ToString(i));


        GText = (GUIText)TextObj.AddComponent(typeof(GUIText));
        GText.text = Pos_In_File.msg;
        GText.material.color = new Color(0 , 0 , 1);
        GText.fontSize = 20;
        GText.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;


        SP = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(new Vector3(Pos_In_File.x , Pos_In_File.y , Pos_In_File.z));
        TextObj.transform.position = SP;


        TextObj.AddComponent(typeof(Follow));

        GameObject OBJ = GameObject.Find(Pos_In_File.Id);
        putTarget =GetComponent<Follow>();
        putTarget.target = OBJ.transform;


    }




}
```

now in last three lines i want to add OBJ to TextOBJ->Follow(Script)->target
What i am messing  up ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Null Exception error in follow class i just have this in update  transform.position = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(target.position);

Comment: ...at what line...for what object. Work with us here lol.

Comment: Last tree line there is no error in codes compile but when i run ...NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i asked this quastion long ago my software have been finnished a 10 month 
and the i get through this problem is

```
void Start () {

        Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
        Ser = new Serial();
        Screen.fullScreen = true;



        Ser.read();


        for (int i =0 ; i < Ser.list.Count; i++)
        {


            Data d = new Data(); 
            d = Ser.list[i];
            GameObject a = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
            a.name = d.Id;
            a.transform.position = new Vector3(d.x,d.y,0);
            a.renderer.material.color = Color.green;

            Data Pos_In_File  = new Data();
            Pos_In_File = Ser.list[i];

            GUIText GText = new GUIText();
            Vector3 SP = new Vector3();
            GameObject TextObj = new GameObject(Pos_In_File.Id+"h");


            GText = (GUIText)TextObj.AddComponent(typeof(GUIText));
            GText.text = Pos_In_File.msg;
            GText.material.color = new Color(0 , 0 , 1);
            GText.fontSize = 20 + (int)Camera.main.transform.position.z;
            GText.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold;


            SP = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(new Vector3(Pos_In_File.x , Pos_In_File.y , Pos_In_File.z));
            TextObj.transform.position = SP;
            TextObj.AddComponent(typeof(Follow));



        }
```